# Delphi Aero Style in Windows XP

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is it possible to make Aero Glass Effect of form and other components in Windows XP using DelphiXE2. If so please tell me how?

Comment: In other news, MS is not going to use glass in Windows 8 so by the time you get this all done in your app, it will be behind the times again. Sometimes it is just easier to ignore these fads and wait for them to pass.

Comment: Yep.  Ugly glass is out, and ugly monochrome is in.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use the Aero Style under Windows XP, the Aero Style is part of the [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(Desktop Window Manager ) which was introduced in Windows Vista, the only option is use a skin library which simulate this look and feel, so try using a library like the [AlphaControls Lite Edition](http://www.alphaskins.com/) components. (Delphi XE2 include a skin library called Vcl Styles, but this doesn't support advanced visualization effects like alpha blending and layered/transparent windows)